# How to format \contentslabel in titletoc?

Tags: titletoc

so in making ToC, `\contentslabel` gives you the section number, and using `\thecontentslabel` give you the default format. The problem is that this number is in arabic, while I want to use roman. Titletoc gave `\contentslabel[<format>]` to reformat this, but it doesn't tell me the wanted format. Any way to reformat it to roman numbering ?

My code is :

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\upshape\filcenter}{CHAPTER \ \Roman{chapter}}{1ex}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\bfseries}%above code
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \thecontentslabel \ }%numbered chapter%
{}%numberless chapter%
{\mdseries\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\bfseries\thecontentspage}%for dots

\chapter{lorem}
\chapter{ipsum}
```

As you can see I format my chapter with roman, but `\thecontentslabel` still gives arabic.
Format I want :

```
CHAPTER I LOREM
CHAPTER II IPSUM
```

the default output:

```
CHAPTER 1 LOREM
CHAPTER 2 IPSUM
```

some of my tried format(all fail):

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\bfseries}%above code
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \contentslabel[\Roman{contentslabel}] \ }%numbered chapter%
{}%numberless chapter%
{\mdseries\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\bfseries\thecontentspage}%for dots

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\bfseries}%above code
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \contentslabel[\Roman{\contentslabel}] \ }%numbered chapter%
{}%numberless chapter%
{\mdseries\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\bfseries\thecontentspage}%for dots

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\bfseries}%above code
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \Roman{\thecontentslabel} \ }%numbered chapter%
{}%numberless chapter%
{\mdseries\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\bfseries\thecontentspage}%for dots

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\bfseries}%above code
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \Roman{thecontentslabel} \ }%numbered chapter%
{}%numberless chapter%
{\mdseries\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\bfseries\thecontentspage}%for dots
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution based on the TeX primitive `\romannumeral`:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\upshape\filcenter}{CHAPTER \ \Roman{chapter}}{1ex}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\bfseries}%above code
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \romannumeral \thecontentslabel}\enspace}%numbered chapter%
{}%numberless chapter%
{\mdseries\titlerule*[0.75em]{.}\bfseries\thecontentspage}%for dots

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{lorem}
\chapter{ipsum}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize that exist. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome! B.t.w., I don't know  why I repeated `\MakeUppercase`. I simplified a bit the code removing it.