# Titletoc appears to truncate part of the title label defined by titlesec

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, titletoc

I have the following MWE where I'm adjusting how my sections are rendered using the `titlesec` package. Based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628934/how-to-format-contentslabel-in-titletoc), I came up with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlelabel{Article \thetitle: }
\titlecontents
    {section}
    [0pt] % mandatory, sets left margin from left page margin
    {} % above code
    {Article \thecontentslabel} % numbered entry
    {} % numberless entry
    {\thecontentspage} % add dots here if desired, filler page format

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents 
    \clearpage

    \section{Intro}
    \section{General}

\end{document}
```

The section labels look like I expect:

[image]

However, the section labels in the table of contents look different:

[image]

I'm not sure why this happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the description of each argument of `\titlecontents` that you already have in your code as comments.

So that modifying the command such a way should do the thing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlelabel{Article \thetitle: }
\titlecontents
    {section}
    [0pt] % mandatory, sets left margin from left page margin
    {} % above code
    {\bf Article \thecontentslabel: } % numbered entry
    {} % numberless entry
    {} % add dots here if desired, filler page format

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents 
    \clearpage

    \section{Intro}
    \section{General}

\end{document}
```

[image]